# Pictures undefined with multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, multer

images.files are undefined with multer. when I simply use router.post...
it works, but if I use authRouter it doesn't work anymore, the files are undefined

I'm getting these errors.

error request axios:

AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
:
"ERR_BAD_RESPONSE"
config
:
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message
:
"Request failed with status code 500"
name

erro in server console.log

```
 TypeError: images is not iterable
        at RepublicaController.adicionaFotosRepublica (C:\projeto\AluEasyNode\server\Controllers\RepublicaController.js:270:27)
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
    [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
```

Client:

```
const formData = new FormData();
this.selectedImages.forEach(image => {
     formData.append('images[]', image.file);
                
});

axios.post(`/a/republica/store/pictures/${this.$route.params.id_repu}`, formData)
.then(() => {
      router.push('/');         

}).catch((error) =>{
   console.error('Erro na solicitação HTTP:', error);
});
```

Config/multer.js:

```
const multer = require("multer");

const path = require("path");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    const destination = "./uploads";
    cb(null, destination);

  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const uniqueFilename = Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname);
    console.log("Nome do arquivo gerado:", uniqueFilename);
    cb(null, uniqueFilename);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

module.exports = upload;
```

Routers.js

```
const express = require('express');
const upload = require('./config/multer');
const republicaController = require('./Controllers/RepublicaController')
const guestRouter = express.Router();
const authRouter = express.Router();
const router = express.Router();

authRouter.post('/republica/store/pictures/:repu_id', upload.array('images[]'), republicaController.adicionaFotosRepublica);

router.use('/a', authRouter);
router.use('/g', guestRouter);

module.exports = router;
```

controller.js

```
RepublicaController.adicionaFotosRepublica =  async (req, res) => {

  try 
  {
      const images = req.files;      
      const republica = await Republica.findOne({_id: req.params.repu_id});
         
      for (const image of images) {
        await saveFile(image.filename);
        republica.pictures.push(image.filename);
        console.log('Images:', image.filename);
     }

     const response = await republica.save();
     return res.status(200).json({status: 'sucesso'})


  } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ error })
  }
  

}
```

Comment: Can you tell us how `req.files` looks alike? Can you console.log it and tell us the result?

Comment: req.files is undefined

Comment: I believe the problem is related to the multer, but I don't know what the solution is @LajosArpad

Comment: It is undefined. This is the problem. I unfortunately do not know much about multer to help you further.